Two visual codes
Here are two codes I can't seem to break.
I have no idea for the first one, and I found some interesting things for the second.
The answer is supposed to either be an English word/phrase, or a number for each.
Also the number in the corner of image 2 is unrelated to the puzzle.



Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

This puzzle comes from an email sent out by my school's STEM Board.

Is it part of a puzzle competition for students or something? What is the purpose of solving it?

Its not a competition

for a promotion of our stem program to the school they released this series of puzzles

I think you have to cut out the bottom ones and overlay them/drag them acros on the initial image; it's hard to do with the current image quality and my setup.

The first is just

 the Burmese word for Myanmar/Burma. The answer could just be one of those. Or, given the alternating pattern, perhaps we're supposed to apply it to "Burma" and get B(u)R(m)A?

The second...

 These are just Code39 barcodes, the standard barcode encoding.
 Scanning the barcodes (or manually decoding them, as I did) gives:
P = 227
Q = 349
N = 79223
E = 17
C = 7412

 As codewarrior0 recognized in the comments, these are values for the RSA cryptosystem, which can be decoded here; the message decodes to hi.


Hmmm that second one doesnt look specific to my school. Ill work on it a little more today and get back to you.
Thank you!

rot13(Gur frpbaq bar tvirf cnenzrgref gb n jryy-xabja zbqrea pelcgbflfgrz.)

What cryptosystem is it?
